# how to open port of docker container with bridge network

Tags: docker, port

I want to open port on docker container.
but not using docker run -p option.
because container have assigned independent IP address by bridge network.
so my system don't need port forwarding.

for example.
host OS has IP 172.30.1.2
container has IP 172.30.1.3
so I want to connect the container with 172.30.1.3:80 directly.

then, I tried something using iptables. but it is denied.

are there some way possible?

Comment: There's -P/--publish-all https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports did you try that?

Comment: Actually this should work exactly the way you are describing. You should be able to access it using `172.30.1.3:80` address, no iptables manipulations required. Are you sure this is the right address? How did you find it out?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify an IP endpoint when exposing ports. For example: `-p 172.30.1.3:80:80`

Check documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/)